# Updating redux store after graphql query

Tags: reactjs, redux, store, graphql

I have a component which shows are list of transactions from a graphql query.
I have another component to make payment. I want to be able to make a payment and then show the new payment in the transaction list.

The approach i am using it to query the data and put it in the store. Once the user make a payment i will update the store and the other component should update with the new props.

Any idea how can i achieve this?

Comment: And i have a show more button which queries the next 10 records for transaction.

Comment: If you are using Apollo Client, you can update store in `then` section of mutation calling, because mutation is Promise.

Comment: its a query, not a mutation and called with component itself

Comment: All Apollo queries have `loading` field. When `loading` changed from true to false, you can update store